# return UserID in add_action

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add a user id into a cookie. There appear to be a lot of posts on the subject. All are based around the following assignment

```html
function TheFunction() {
 global $current_user;
 get_currentuserinfo();
 $id = $current_user->ID;
 setcookie('cookiename', 'hello'.$id, time()+3600*24*100, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false);
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'TheFunction');
```

The hook is working and passing the value into the cookie, but failing to return any user parameters (e.g. my cookie value is hello0). I've tried wp_login and wp_authenticate to ensure that a $current_user exists. I'm now running our of ideas.

Can you help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, for whatever reason, the `$current_user` cannot be populated at that particular point, even though the user has just logged in. You can work around this by using the user object that is passed to the `wp_login` action.

```
add_action('wp_login', function($username, $user) {
    setcookie('cookiename', 'hello'. $user->ID, time()+3600*24*100, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false);
}, 10, 2);
```